# How to get substring from the sentence in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get specific substring in specific condition.

1. if the string is "Update xxx.csv /addroles" then `ProcessCommandAsync(input.Substring(0, split), input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex), input.Substring(indexOfChar + 1))` should contain firstparameter `Update` ,second parameter `xxx.csv` and third should be `addroles`.
2. if the string is  "Update xxx.csv" then the it should return first parameter `update` and second one `xxx.csv`.

There is an issue if I provide only 2 parameters. It complains about

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Length cannot be less than zero.
>   Parameter name: length'

```
public async Task WaitForInputAsync()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Command: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                var split = input.IndexOf(" ");              
                var indexOfChar = input.IndexOf('/');          

                int startIndex = input.IndexOf(input.Substring(split + 1));
                int endIndex = input.IndexOf("/") + (("/").Length)-1;
                if (split >= 0)
                {             
                    await ProcessCommandAsync(input.Substring(0, split), input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex), input.Substring(indexOfChar + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    await ProcessCommandAsync(input);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the [`Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=netframework-4.8) method

> Returns the element at a specified index in a sequence or a default
>   value if the index is out of range.

```
var s = input.Split(' ')
             .Select(x => x.TrimStart('/'))
             .ToArray();

ProcessCommand(s.ElementAtOrDefault(0), s.ElementAtOrDefault(1), s.ElementAtOrDefault(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Command Parsing. Don't make one on your own, use one of the fully tested, functional, open source and community checked project you can find in the web.

Sometimes in small hobby projects I used this: https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

This isn't the unique option, there are a lot of different projects that are focused in this thing.

Edit: If you want to learn more of the topic you can read this article in codeproject, but not the only one: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236763/Flexible-Csharp-Command-Line-Parsing-via-Attribute

Also, I have to say "attribute-way" is not the only way to do achieve it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting me to do. I saw that solution but it is not relevant to me question. Please provide proper solution.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to make much sense in the context of OP's question. Did you answer the right question?

Comment: @MVC , if I'm not mistaken, you're handling with command parsing. My answer is "don't handle it, use an already created command parser in the community". Command parsing is not only valid in start-applications-args environment. You can use wherever you want (internally). I don't know if I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the above example "Update xxx.csv /addroles", I would split the input string by a space character and then use **switch** to execute the method depending on how many sub strings you have...

```
string input = "Update xxx.csv /addroles";
string[] strings = input.Split(' '); //split string at space char
int stringCnt = strings.Length; //get string count

switch(stringCnt) {
    case 0:
        //do something?
        break;
    case 1:
        await ProcessCommandAsync(strings[0]);
        break;
    case 2:
        await ProcessCommandAsync(strings[0], strings[1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        await ProcessCommandAsync(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2].TrimStart('/'));   
        break;
    default:
        //do something?
        break;
}//switch
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not checking whether index is valid.

```
int endIndex = input.IndexOf("/") + (("/").Length)-1;
```

`endIndex` is -1 if '/' doesn't exists.

```
// endIndex - startIndex is less than 0;
input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex),
```

I copy your code below and leave comments on the position.

```
public async Task WaitForInputAsync()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Command: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            var split = input.IndexOf(" ");

            // This could be -1 if '/' is not found        
            var indexOfChar = input.IndexOf('/');          

            int startIndex = input.IndexOf(input.Substring(split + 1));
            int endIndex = input.IndexOf("/") + (("/").Length)-1;
            if (split >= 0)
            {             
                await ProcessCommandAsync(input.Substring(0, split), 

            // endIndex - startIndex is less than 0;
             input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex), 

             input.Substring(indexOfChar + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                await ProcessCommandAsync(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I'll suggest to take a look at @DrkDeveloper 's answer, parsing command is pain in the neck..